# Custom theme only updates if I run bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, custom-theme

Newbie so apologies if I get some of the terminology wrong.

I've recently started working with Magento using Mark Shust's docker version and getting along ok. However, my custom theme that inherits from blank has stopped updating automatically.

Clearing the caches either by command or emptying the relevant cache folders doesn't seem to work - the only thing that seems to update the site is bin/magento setup:upgrade.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong / maybe upset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the cache from magento
[Check doc here](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/preprocess/#debug-in-server-side-compilation-mode)

clear `var/cache` `var/view_preprocessed` and `pub/static`

```
bin/magento c:f && rm -rf pub/static/* var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*
```

If clearing the cache doesn't work but xml file does. Be sure your theme is set to 0 in database

```
SELECT * FROM magento2.theme;
```

> Type of your theme SHOULD be 0

(type 1 is for virtual theme and won't use less file in your theme)

**EDIT**

Command for markshust/docker-magento

```
bin/clinotty sh -c 'rm -rf pub/static/* var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*'
```

Base command

> bin/clinotty sh -c '[your command]'

For more explanation see @Cladiuss comment

Comment: Unfortunately not. Clearing the caches doesn't work and on checking the database my theme has a type of 0.

Comment: Can you try this please : 
`bin/clinotty sh -c 'rm -rf pub/static/* var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*'`
Can you share the commands you used before this bug happend ? Maybe you need to replace the 'rm -rf' command by the one you used before.

This would be something like that : `bin/clinotty sh -c '[your command]'`

Comment: OK, apologies, I come from 20 years of M$ Stack... that worked!  (THANK YOU!) Why does clinotty work when straight from the cmd line doesn't?

Comment: If you go inside your container, it should work. But when using an `*` in a command from outside, it is expanded by your shell **before** it enters the container. So it cannot see the files inside your container. [Here is a better explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50745274/3077606).